# How to send bool value on this URL in my asp.net mvc aplication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code I am trying to send one more bool value to the URL..

and its goign to the ActionResult Perfectly

```
 public virtual ActionResult Index( int? id,bool? check ) {
}
```

But check allways geting null value?

is that something I am doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for

```
RedirectUrl = string.Format( "/BvIndex/Index/{0}/" + check + "?bvIndex-mode=select", iReturn )
```

you need an action method with three parameters (not exactly the following but something like this)

```
 public virtual ActionResult Index( int? id,bool? check, string bvIndex-mode ) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered a route key that corresponds to check in your global.asax?

Comment: No no no.. why in the world would you need to change your route just to accept an extra querystring value for an action?